# Chrome Mobile: URL bar causes trouble with footer

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome-app

I am currently facing a trouble with Chrome Mobile version 71.

The problem is the follow, the address bar. I tried to use:

```
<script>
   alert($(window).innherHeight())
   alert($(window).outerHeight())
   alert($(window).height())
</script>
```

and they all return the same height, however, due to the address bar, they should not. So, what is the problem? When, I try to put a footer in the webpage (by using position absolute and bottom: 0), the footer appears correctly in the firefox on my phone, and in the chrome mobile, in my laptop (because there is no address bar). However, in the chrome application in my android the footer does not appear until I reach the end of the page.

I tried some work around:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
            // This hides the address bar:
            window.scrollTo(0, 1);

    }, 0);
});
```

and similars that I found in other answers. However, they either do not work, or even if they do, they make the webpage look bad when the address bar disappears (because the user reached the end of page, or something similar).

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not the best answer, but frankly was the one that worked better for me:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mobile") != -1){
    $('body').css("max-height", $(window).outerHeight());
    $('body').css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight());
    $( window ).resize(function(e) {
      $('body').css("max-height", $(window).outerHeight());
      $('body').css("min-height", $(window).outerHeight());
  });
}
```